# How do you read a property from a parent object's DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

If I have a situation like this:

```
<Parent DataContext="...">
    <Child DataContext="..." />
</Parent>
```

How can the Child access a property on the Parent's DataContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on how you want to access the property, and where it is targeted.  You can access it directly *from XAML* by using `RelativeSource`:

```
<Parent DataContext="{...}">
    <Child DataContext="{...}"
        TargetProperty="{Binding 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Parent},
            Path=DataContext.Property}" 
     />
</Parent>
```

This assumes you have, or can create, a dependency property `TargetProperty` on `Child`.

Alternatively, if you want to access a property of the parent's view model *from the child's view model*, then you might want to consider passing a reference, or an encapsulated reference, or a weak reference, to the child's view model.

Answer (score 2):

By using a [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.aspx) with [`FindAncestor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode.aspx) Mode:

```
<Grid>
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SomeProperty}">
     <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <!-- Here, the DataContext is SomeProperty, so you need to use a RelativeSource to reach the Grid's DataContext -->
             <TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.SomeGridViewModelProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
  </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the parent object's DC has a property Foo, to read Foo.Bar:

```
DataContext="{Binding Foo}" Text="{Binding Bar}"
```

OR

```
Text="{Binding Foo.Bar}"
```